# UserControl Events are very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have recently started to move my user controls in DLLs. These controls usually look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DialogBase.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="OK" Click="OkButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to able to use every button in the control like in a standard control. For example when somebody uses the control above, he should be able to handle the click event in an own method like this:

```
<lib:UserControl1 
        OkButtonClick="MyCostomClickMethod"
        />
```

I usualy achieve this like this: (code-behind file of user control)

```
    public static RoutedEvent OkButtonClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("OkButtonClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UserControl1));

    public event RoutedEventHandler OkButtonClick
    {
        add 
        { 
            AddHandler(OkButtonClickEvent, value); 
        }
        remove
        {
            RemoveHandler(OkButtonClickEvent, value);
        }
    }

    private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(OkButtonClickEvent));
    }
```

This works fine but very slow. The delay between a click and the resulting action can be up to a second. Can somebody tell me if there is a faster or in any way better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the eventhandler at design time?

Comment: Are you doing any CPU intensive tasks in your handlers?

Comment: No, they are close to empty, I just added a messagebox or console output to them.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Command in the class the you actually want the event. Then bind the Button Command to it. You can create your own Command or use something like a [DelegateCommand](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2009/04/mvvm-infrastructure-delegatecommand.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. I have read about ICommand before but always used it in another way. However I still wonder how I can use this the way I want. I want the user of the user control to be able to use it like a normal windows wpf-control without knowing or even seeing the code behind it. I want a way that allows me to provide a simple solution for the user, passing a command and a command parameter seems a little to much. Do you have any suggestions for me? So just that you know, I am still working on this and when I find a solution that fits me, I will give you the credit for it.

Comment: I dont think your way is the best solution. I would suggest using mine